# Term for a toroidal-shaped, winter garment worn on the neck, not scarf, often made of polar fleece (pictures)

Tags: single-word-requests

The question title describes very succintly the object I'm looking it's name or term in English. I know the name in spanish in Argentina, it's ["cuello polar"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuello_polar), cuello means neck, polar refers to ["polar fleece"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_fleece) a type of cloth. It's not a scarf

[Here there is search of images of "cuello polar"](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=polar%20cuello%20wiki&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=638&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit6Kf68_vPAhUBI2MKHR9oAHYQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=cuello%20polar),

These are typical:
[image: Fleece collar]
[image: Collar with drawstring]

Note: This can be worn as a hat to cover one's head too, but it's not ideal, since it's open on both ends and the top of the head with the hole could be exposed, in comparison to a real closed winter hat.

Is worn around the neck, it's toroidal shaped, it's made of polar fleece often, it's goal it's to warm the neck but also can be used to cover mouth and nose, it's normally used in winter with low temperatures.

Comment: I've heard it called a buff, but that might be branded. We also say balaclava, even though that isn't exactly what a balaclava is.

Comment: They are called *neck warmers*.

Comment: Is definitely not a Balaclava because it's not toroidal shaped like the google images I provide. A buff didn't provide me similar images to the search I provide in the post, they are in cloth area larger than "cuello polar".

Comment: @Mick Yes that seems very close, the google search images of that show various matches to my google image search, [such as this one](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=neck+warmer&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=638&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0ycWk-fvPAhUXz2MKHdBeCEkQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=KdmWROhAVPsCJM%3A).

Comment: Also "winter collar": https://www.google.it/search?q=winter+colla&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL1pDO-fvPAhWqC8AKHf78C6cQ_AUIBygB&biw=768&bih=909#hl=it&tbm=isch&q=winter+collar

Comment: In ski resort shops in France, they're often called _cache-cols_. I've bought mine in one such shop, and as a result I've never actually known what to call it in any other language than French. I've been referring to it as my ‘necktube’ or my ‘fluffyfleecepullovertheneckwarmerthingy’ in English.

Comment: @mplungjan To who are you responding with that comment? My images are perfectly describing what I need, and they are working.

Comment: I thought you wanted to embed them, they are links to seaches. Apologies

Comment: Embedding them for you since links go stale

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, I was considering doing it myself but it raised me doubts about if if the formatting was going to look good, if it was desirable to have the giants image to display by themselves instead of giving the viewers of the question the option to display them by clicking, all this complex thought I'll leave it to others that know more than me, hopefully you are one of them.

Comment: If I were to knit a garment like the one pictured, I would call it a [cowl][1]. 


  [1]: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cowl

I only now realized how poorly that word fits, but it is pretty widely used in the knitting/crafting world. If you do an image search for knitted cowl, you will rarely see one that incorporates a hood.

Answer (score 19):

There doesn't seem to be consensus (though I do feel like if I was currently in a colder climate a word would immediately come to mind).

Buffwear is a clothing company that sells this product. They refer to generically as a [**neck warmer**](http://www.buffwear.co.uk/buff-adult-headwear/neckwarmer-pro-buff).

REI, the outdoor equipment company, refers to the category as [**neck gaiters**](https://www.rei.com/c/mens-neck-gaiters).

---

[Edit] Taking this distinction from Choster in the comments:

> Neck gaiter seems to be the term favored by outdoor recreation equipent manufacturers and retailers, whereas neck warmer comes first for department stores and Etsy accounts, although there is considerable overlap. e4hats.com calls the category neck bands, a subcategory of bands & warmers.

Comment: They are very similar to what I'm looking for, I'll wait to see if another names arise.

Comment: +1 for Neck gaiters. That is the normal term for outdoor recreation and climbing.

Comment: *Neck gaiter* seems to be the term favored by outdoor recreation equipent manufacturers and retailers, whereas *neck warmer* comes first for department stores and Etsy accounts, although there is considerable overlap. e4hats.com calls the category *neck bands*, a subcategory of *bands & warmers*.

Comment: In the UK these are mainly worn by motorcyclists, to protect against wind chill in winter. They are sold as "neck warmers" or "neck warmer tubes".

Comment: I would only ever have thought of calling it a neck warmer. Haven't had a motorbike in years but I still have a couple of these, they are great in the UK in Winter!

Comment: Not really sure why I keep getting votes for this...

Answer (score 2):

There's a garment serving that function that is called a *snood* in UK English. See for instance [here](http://www.superdry.com/search/snood?gclid=CjwKEAjw7svABRCi_KPzoPr53QoSJAABSvxfztVCyJLO734d4vrXq1Ewu8v_CBeDoYw73WY8LeXVwxoCyL7w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Comment: I am more used to seeing snood in this sense: http://www.james-joyce-music.com/song01_lyrics.html

Comment: No, that's a little similar but too different. "cuello polar" contains much less cloth than that. That seems much bigger.

Comment: Snood is also (and from earlier) used for a rather different article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snood_(headgear)

Answer (score 0):

The name is ***Thermal Neck Warmer***. See some [here in amazon.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0168SVTPM) They also call them ***Winter Fleece Snood***.

Answer (score 0):

Growing up in Upstate New York, we called a similar item of clothing a ***dickie***:

> an article of clothing made to look like the front or collar of a shirt, blouse, vest, etc., worn as a separate piece under another garment, as a jacket or dress.
>
> ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dickie))

Usually they resembled the neck portion of a turtleneck, and had a bib-like portion that laid over the back and chest. I can imagine the word being extended to cover the type of garment you show.

Here's a [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dickie&biw=1565&bih=820&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzptnLnojQAhVL64MKHYTrCd4Q_AUIkwMoAQ).

Answer (score -1):

There's an article of clothing called a "**muff**", which [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/muff) defines as:

> tube made of fur or other warm material into which the hands are placed for warmth.

The word "muff" can also evidently be used for clothing designed to keep other parts of the body warm, notably as in "earmuffs".  From this, one could make the argument that the article of clothing pictured qualifies as a muff.